# Morris line chart y axis going beyond 100%

Tags: morris.js

I am using Morris line chart but my y axis is going beyond 100%.

Below is my json data:

```
[
  {"y":"20/03","Threshold":"70","x TV":"0","x CA":"100","x Retail":"0","x Mobility":"100","x Media":"0"},
  {"y":"21/03","Threshold":"70","x TV":"100","x CA":"87.69","x Retail":"100","x Mobility":"70","x Media":"86.67"},
  {"y":"22/03","Threshold":"70","x TV":"0","x CA":"87.5","x Retail":"100","x Mobility":"93.42","x Media":"82.14"},
  {"y":"23/03","Threshold":"70","x TV":"0","x CA":"0","x Retail":"0","x Mobility":"0","x Media":"0"},
  {"y":"24/03","Threshold":"70","x TV":"0","x CA":"0","x Retail":"0","x Mobility":"0","x Media":"0"},
  {"y":"25/03","Threshold":"70","x TV":"0","x CA":"0","x Retail":"0","x Mobility":"0","x Media":"0"},
  {"y":"26/03","Threshold":"70","x TV":"0","x CA":"0","x Retail":"0","x Mobility":"0","x Media":"0"}
]
```

Please find below Morris line chart code:

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'morris-line-chart',
    data: jsonData,
    xkey: 'y',
    xLabels: 'day',
    ykeys: ['x TV', 'x CA', 'x Retail', 'x Mobility', 'x Media', 'Threshold'],
    ymax: 100,
    ymin:0,
    labels: ['x TV', 'x CA', 'x Retail', 'x Mobility', 'x Media', 'Threshold'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: false,
    parseTime: false,
    lineColors: ['#C91530', '#871A35', '#E25D00', '#8EADB8', '#F2A200', '#D4D4D4'],
    //yLabelFormat: function (y) { return y.toString(); },
    postUnits: '%'
});
```

For date 21/03 and 22/03 x Retail has value as 100% my observation that path element not drawing the straight line.

Answer (score 4):

The line goes beyond 100% because, by default, Morris.Line is set to draw curved lines (smooth: true). That's why, even if you don't have values greater than 100%, the line goes beyond 100%.

If you don't want to have curved lines, you can set the `smooth` property to false:

```
smooth: false
```

But there's no property in the latest Morris version (0.5.1) to not curve the line if the value reaches the `ymax`.

```js
var jsonData = [
    { "y": "20/03", "Threshold": "70", "x TV": "0", "x CA": "100", "x Retail": "0", "x Mobility": "100", "x Media": "0" }, 
    { "y": "21/03", "Threshold": "70", "x TV": "100", "x CA": "87.69", "x Retail": "100", "x Mobility": "70", "x Media": "86.67" }, 
    { "y": "22/03", "Threshold": "70", "x TV": "0", "x CA": "87.5", "x Retail": "100", "x Mobility": "93.42", "x Media": "82.14" }, 
    { "y": "23/03", "Threshold": "70", "x TV": "0", "x CA": "0", "x Retail": "0", "x Mobility": "0", "x Media": "0" }, 
    { "y": "24/03", "Threshold": "70", "x TV": "0", "x CA": "0", "x Retail": "0", "x Mobility": "0", "x Media": "0" }, 
    { "y": "25/03", "Threshold": "70", "x TV": "0", "x CA": "0", "x Retail": "0", "x Mobility": "0", "x Media": "0" }, 
    { "y": "26/03", "Threshold": "70", "x TV": "0", "x CA": "0", "x Retail": "0", "x Mobility": "0", "x Media": "0" }]

Morris.Line({
    element: 'morris-line-chart',
    data: jsonData,
    xkey: 'y',
    xLabels: 'day',
    ykeys: ['x TV', 'x CA', 'x Retail', 'x Mobility', 'x Media', 'Threshold'],
    ymax: 100,
    ymin:0,
    labels: ['x TV', 'x CA', 'x Retail', 'x Mobility', 'x Media', 'Threshold'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: false,
    parseTime: false,
    smooth: false,
    lineColors: ['#C91530', '#871A35', '#E25D00', '#8EADB8', '#F2A200', '#D4D4D4'],
    //yLabelFormat: function (y) { return y.toString(); },
    postUnits: '%'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="morris-line-chart"></div>
```